# Is vanilla spectator mode secure?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a private server with a bunch of friends and I was thinking, since spectator mode is a thing now, to open it to public and have the default gamemode be spectator mode so guests can snoop around without the risk of them doing anything bad.

This would - of course - only work if people couldn't do anything bad, like disturb people, cause lag  or destroy things.

I did a quick google search and I couldn't find any known bugs or exploits

Can I assume it's secure (on the current stable release - as of writing this 1.8) then?

Comment: I don't know of any insecurities with spectator mode. All it does is let people be invisible to other players, and quite simply "noclip" through the terrain to look around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe spectator mode is safe, the only lag that might possibly come from spectator mode is chunk loading and also just having many players on the server. IIRC spectators can chat though...

EDIT: In 1.9, there is a gamerule called `spectatorsGenerateChunks` that will assist with the chunk loading.

Comment: Chunk generation might be an issue indeed since they can fly pretty fast and even a world border doesnt stop them (just tested this)

Comment: When there is at least 1 player which isn't in spectator mode, players in spectator mode will not affect world generation and chunk loading.

Answer (score 1):

A seen on the spectator mode wiki page (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spectator), players can in spectator mode:

> fly, clip through blocks and entities, and view invisible players.

It is also mentioned that they cannot interact with GUIs and they can take the POV of a non-player mob. If you don't want your players doing this, I'd recommend not giving your players specator mode. Spectator mode does not have any known exploits at the moment that would allow players to interrupt the game, however.